# How Can I get executable sql statement from linq or IQueryable object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

When I debug the code I always use query.ToString() to get the sql statement, but the sql statement contains many linq parameter like `@p__linq__0`, `@p__linq__1`, `@p__linq__2` and so on. It can't be executed in Sql Server Management studio directly,  I need to replace the `@p__linq__0` with the actual parameter value. It is cockamamie! So, how Can I get  executable sql statement from linq or `IQueryable` object? Thank you very much!

The sql is always something as below:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[IsCuepool] = @p__linq__0) AND 
    ([Extent1].[IsInvalid] = @p__linq__1) AND 
    ([Extent1].[IsRecovery] = @p__linq__2) AND 
    (([Extent1].[CustomerName] LIKE @p__linq__3 ESCAPE N'~') OR 
    ([Extent1].[QQ] LIKE @p__linq__4 ESCAPE N'~') OR 
    ([Extent1].[Phone] LIKE @p__linq__5 ESCAPE N'~') OR 
    ([Extent1].[BFAccount] LIKE @p__linq__6 ESCAPE N'~')) AND 
    (([Extent1].[CreateAt] = (LOWER(CASE WHEN (@p__linq__7 IS NULL) ......
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a statement without parameters. The SQL is not created with the intention to make it easy to copy, paste and execute it, but to make it secure to run the query. Using parameters instead of a composed SQL query is an important security feature to prevent SQL injection, so there's a good reason why things are how they are.

Comment: Thank you Sefe! I know SQL injection. but what I want is just a method like query.GetExecutableSql() which is a debug tool method, I don't think that contradict security of Sql injection. And I think I even can implement a method like QueryHelper.GetExecutableSql(query) by myself. I wonder if entityframework has a similar method?

Comment: @Farwell_Liu I don't know of any such method. And yes, you can create such a method yourself, but it will be probably not easy, since you will have to walk through the expression tree the same way that EF does.

Answer (score 1):

I meet a situation like this.
I defined some variables in tsql just on top of entity framework script. This let me not have to make changes on copy script

like this

```
 DECLARE @p__linq__0 INT = 1;
 DECLARE @p__linq__1 INT = 2;

 SELECT *
 FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
 WHERE ([Extent1].[IsCuepool] = @p__linq__0) AND 
 ([Extent1].[IsInvalid] = @p__linq__1) AND 
 ([Extent1].[IsRecovery] = @p__linq__2) AND 
 (([Extent1].[CustomerName] LIKE @p__linq__3 ESCAPE N'~') OR 
 ([Extent1].[QQ] LIKE @p__linq__4 ESCAPE N'~') OR 
 ([Extent1].[Phone] LIKE @p__linq__5 ESCAPE N'~') OR 
 ([Extent1].[BFAccount] LIKE @p__linq__6 ESCAPE N'~')) AND 
 (([Extent1].[CreateAt] = (LOWER(CASE WHEN (@p__linq__7 IS NULL) ......
```

Comment: Thank you Dan Nguyen, Your approach has some help for me.